# C++11 on Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2005, legacy-code, multiplatform

I'm handling with some multiplatform legacy code, and there is a requirement that should compile on Visual Studio 2005.

VS 2005 supports C++11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't.

VS2008 has TR1 ([assuming sufficient service packs](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f131e9ba-ed85-4995-9acb-7675666b94c8/tr1-for-visual-studio-2005)), which are some new components of the standard library like std::tr1::shared_ptr that have made their way into the standard with C++11, but it does not have new language features like lambdas, rvalue references, etc. or library features like threading or std::unique_ptr.

You can get the same effect in VS2005 with Boost's TR1 library. Then if you want cross-compiler support, you can do, e.g.,

```
#include <boost/tr1/memory.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<int> pi( new int(42) );
    // ...
}
```

On platforms with their own TR1 implementations, Boost will use those automatically. On platforms without TR1, it will use its own implementation, imported into the std::tr1 namespace.

Comment: Thanks! It was the answer that I need. For now I don't need to compile in VS2005. Maybe I can compile on VS2010. But I need to wait the Windows developement turn. I'm trying to persuade to abandon VS2005! :)

Comment: FWIW, Here's a list of [C++11 support in VS compilers from 2010 up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

Comment: The feature I'm using is only supported on VS2013! Microsoft is not a good choice! :(